# call controller method using jquery

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, request

I am trying to fetch an article from the db using jquery code 
this is the jquery function

```
function searchArticle(codeArticle){
    if(codeArticle){
        //alert(codeArticle);
        var detailHtml ="";


        $.getJSON("detailArticle",
                    {   
                        codeArticle: codeArticle, 
                        ajax:true   
                    },
                    function(data){
                        if(data){
                            detailHtml+= "<tr>"+
                                    "<td>"+data[0].article.codeArticle+"</td>"+
                                    "<td>1</td>"+
                                    "<td>"+data[0].prixUnitaireTTC+"</td>"+
                                    "<td>0</td>"+
                                     "</tr>";
                            $("#detailNouvelleCommande").append(detailHtml);
                        }else{
                            alert("article not found");
                        }
                    });
    }
}
```

and this is my controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/detailArticle")
    @ResponseBody
    public Article getArticleByCode(String codeArticle){
        if(codeArticle == null){
            return null;
        }
        Article article = articleService.findOne("codeArticle", codeArticle);
        if(article == null){
            return null;
        }
        return article;
    }
```

the method selects the article from database correctly however while returning it I receive the following eror:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class com.stock.mvc.entity.Article
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:187)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
```

Comment: Please check whether Article class has getter/setter for each of its property. Btw line `if(article == null){
            return null;
        }` is redudant here, if article is null it will be returned anyway by the next statement: `return article;`

Comment: ok but article in this case is null, the problem is that the return type is not converted to an xml automatically, I used ObjectMapper to convert it but it is not a clean solution

Comment: here is the solution to convert any object to an xml if(object != null){
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   try {
    return mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
   } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }